# web.config redirect from folder to $_GET query

Tags: redirect, iis

I want to redirect from `example.com/folder` to `example.com/file.php?url=folder` via `web.config`.

How can I make it?

Comment: It is by default not possible. You have to download and install IIS URL Rewrite module, and then add a redirection rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly install the url rewrite extension. Url:https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then you could use below url rewrite rule into web.config  to achieve your requirement.

```
     <rewrite>
<rules>
            <rule name="Addquerystring" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/file.php?url={R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />

            </rule>
</rules>
     </rewrite>
```